# Check if two lists have the same elements

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function wich given two lists returns a boolean responding if the two lists have the same elements, even if they do not appear in the same order. I've got something like this:

```
function :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
function (x:xs) y = elem x y && function xs y
```

The problem with this is that there's no pattern when xs is empty, and I do not have any idea how to deal with that case. Any other way to solve this will be really welcome, I am quite new to Haskell.

Thanks all!

Comment: Instead of adding your solution as an edit - answer you own question. It's [allowed and encouraged!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Hint: what happens if you evaluate `is [1,2,1] [1,2,3]`?

Comment: If you are not satisfied with any of the existing answers, you can actually post your own answer as a reply to this question, and then mark it as accepted. This helps people coming here from Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works as well

```
import Data.List

function :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
function x y = null (x \\ y) && null (y \\ x)
```

Comment: This is wrong, for example `function [1,2] [1,2,3]` returns `True` but the lists are not equal!! The correct answer is `function xs ys = null (xs \\ ys) && null (ys \\ xs).

Comment: In my comment I am assuming that both lists have non-repeated elements. Still, my solution works for repeated elements as long as each element is repeated in the same quantity in both lists.

Answer (score 2):

Use the clause:

```
function [] y = True
```

All the elements of the empty list are in the list `y`.

Comment: I had the function written so that clause didn't worked, and get the correct approach while asking here. Feel so dumb now jaja.Thanks, really!!

Comment: Doesn't properly work with duplicates, and has other issues (see comments on the question).

Answer (score 1):

Your function only checks if one list is a subset of the other. You can apply it in both directions to check if lists have exactly the same elements:

```
contains [] y = True
contains (x:xs) y = elem x y && contains xs y

equals x y = contains x y && contains y x
```

Keep in mind this might not work well for lists with duplicates.